# Zipping folder in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, zip, compression, archive

I'm trying to create an archive of a folder, and then delete that folder:

```kotlin
GlobalScope.launch {
   withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
       val folder = File("./folder/")
       zip(folder, File("./folder.zip")) 
       folder.deleteRecursively()
   }
}
```

The zipping code works, but I can't delete the folder that was archived. `folder.deleteRecursively()` returns false without any errors.

This is the zipping code I'm using:

```kotlin
fun zip(unzipped: File, zipped: File) {
    if (!unzipped.exists() || !unzipped.isDirectory) return
    ZipOutputStream(BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream(zipped))).use { zos ->
        unzipped.walkTopDown().filter { it.absolutePath != unzipped.absolutePath }.forEach { file ->
            val zipFileName = file.absolutePath.removePrefix(unzipped.absolutePath).removePrefix(File.separator)
            val entry = ZipEntry("$zipFileName${(if (file.isDirectory) "/" else "" )}")
            zos.putNextEntry(entry)
            if (file.isFile) file.inputStream().use { it.copyTo(zos) }
        }
    }
}
```

The only reason I can think of why this code fails is unclosed streams, but I can't find any in my code.

Comment: Works fine on my machine. Maybe there are some other processes in the OS, holding the folder (like file manager application or terminal)?

Comment: Are you sure that your coroutines don't swallow the errors?

Comment: It worth checking the folder's flags - the folder might be immutable.